# Kohana framework - Ajax implementation best practices

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I am developing an application in Kohana framework. I would like to know the best practices in implementing ajax in kohana. So far I am using different controller for ajax.  I think the important concerns will be minimizing the resources requirement and handling sessions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm using this:

In Controller_Template:

```
    public function before()
    {
        $this->auto_render = ! $this->request->is_ajax(); 
        if($this->auto_render === TRUE)
        {
            parent::before();
        }
    }
```

And inside my actions:

```
      if ($this->request->is_ajax())    
        {
            ...         
            $this->response->headers('Content-type','application/json; charset='.Kohana::$charset);
            $this->response->body($jsonEncoded);
        }
```

Comment: this is good.. i will surely make use of this... thanks.. Anyway i expect more suggestions that will be useful for the whole community..

Answer (score 5):

As the fellas above said, you don't need a separate controller for your ajax actions. You may take advantage of Kohana's request object to identify the request type. This may be done in the following way:

```
<?php

class Controller_Test extends Controller_Template {
    /**
     * @var     View    Template container
     */
    protected $template = 'template';
    /**
     * @var     View    Content to render
     */
    protected $content = 'some/content/view';
    // Inherited from parent class
    protected $auto_template_render = TRUE;
    public function before()
    {
        parent::before();
        if ($this->request->is_ajax() OR !$this->request->is_initial()) {
            $this->auto_template_render = FALSE;
        }    
    }

    public function after()
    {
        if ($this->auto_template_render == FALSE) {
            // We have ajax or internal request here
            $this->template = $this->content;            
        } else {
            // We have regular http request for a page
            $this->template = View::factory($this->template)
                ->set('content', $this->content);
        }
        // Call parent method
        parent::after();
    }
}
```

Though the example is very simple it may be improved to what you want to archive. Basically I've finished up writing my own `Controller_Template` to do the stuff I need. Also you may consider adding the format parameter to your urls so that the `.html` urls returned the regular html representation of the data and `.json` urls did the same, but in json format.
For more information (and probably ideas) see [kerkness unofficial Kohana wiki](http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=template-site:extending_the_template_controller)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a separate controller, you can use Kohana_Controller_Template for handling AJAX requests as well.

It's up to you to decide what will the response be in case of AJAX request (or subrequest, it's usually the same). I usually have the template actually rendered only in case of request being the initial one (and not-ajax), rendering it's $content var otherwise.

Also, you can easily check if a request is AJAX / subrequest:

```
if ($request->is_ajax())
if ( ! $request->is_initial())
```

Comment: All my controllers extends Controller_DefaultTemplate which extends Kohana_Controller_Template. I am assigning many things in before() method of my DefaultTemplate which is not required while requesting through ajax. So I decided to use a different controller for ajax requests even though it extends Kohana_Controller_Template. Hope this makes sence.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if using Kohana_Controller_Template as your controller parent/ancestor it is good to remember to disable auto-rendering when accessing via AJAX, to prevent loading and rendering whole template.

```
if ($request->is_ajax()) $this->auto_render = FALSE;
```